# Call to after results in RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter

I'm using tkinter and I am trying to compare a string [in this case, the original file] to text in a text widget. Here's the function and where I call the function:

```
def checkText():
    if(text.get("1.0", "end-1c") != currentText):
        print("Changed")

    root.after(1000, checkText())
```

and where I call:

```
root.after(1000, checkText()) #after 1 second, check text to see if it has changed
```

It returns the error:

```
  File "main.py", line 65, in checkText
  if(text.get("1.0", "end-1c") != currentText):
  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Except with hundreds of 'File "main.py", line 65, in checkText'

Probably something obvious I'm overlooking, but help is appreciated.

Those are the only places the function is used or referenced to in the program, but just incase, here is where currentText is defined:

```
myfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title='Open a file', mode='r')
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    loadedfile = myfile.read()
    currentText = myfile.read()
```

loadedFile is put directly into the text widget and works fine, so I assume currentText should be the same as loadedFile/text in the widget.

Thanks.

edit: formatting, also I realized I can just say `currentText = loadedFile` to simplify it, but I am keeping the original code in the question

edit: Entire function for getting text

```
def fileOpen(textView):
try:
    myfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(title='Open a file', mode='r')
    text.delete('1.0', END)
    loadedfile = myfile.read()
    currentText = loadedFile
    currentFile = myfile.name
    currentName = currentFile
    currentName = currentName.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] #get the 'name.ext' part only
    currentName = currentName.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1] #incase you're using windows
    currentFileButton.config(text = currentName)
    myfile.close()
    textView.insert("end", loadedfile)
except:
    return

def saveAs(): #define how to save files
try:
    global text
    t = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    saveLocation = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
    file1 = open(saveLocation, "w+")
    file1.write(t)
    file1.close()
except:
    return
```

later:

```
text = Text(textFrame, bd=0, bg=color, fg=textColor) #make text editor box
```

Comment: It looks like the recursion comes from `text.get("1.0", "end-1c") != currentText`. To confirm this, try and add an `else` clause that prints something if the condition is not satisfied. If you do so, does something get printed?

Comment: @Rightleg I added `else: print("Not changed")` and the same error occurs, no change.

Comment: Of course this could not solve the problem, but is `"Changed"` or `"Not changed"` ever printed?

Comment: @Rightleg Not changed is printed above the long error

Comment: `"Not changed"` is printed only once?

Comment: @Rightleg Many times. edit: more than i care to count

Comment: What's `text`, and what's its `get` method?

Comment: @Rightleg Changed original answer to show.

Comment: I need the declaration of `text`, specifically, what's its type?

Comment: @Rightleg There it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. As you said, it's obvious, but actually not so obvious.

The problem lies in your call to `after`.

When calling `after`, you need to pass a time, and a *callback*, which is the function that will be called after the given time. Note that what must be passed is a **function**.

But when you call `root.after(1000, checkText())`, the second argument is **not** a function. It's a *value*, that corresponds to the return value of the `checkText` function.

---

What happens when you pass `checkText()` to `after`:

1. `checkText` is called with no arguments
2. The returned value is passed to `after`

But when you call `checkText`, a new call to `root.after(1000, checkText())` is reached, and `checkText()` must be evaluated, so `checkText` is called.

Every call is immediate (ie, it does not occur after `1000`ms), because the `checkText()` expression needs to be evaluated in order to be passed to `after`.

---

As I said, the second argument for the `after` method is a function. Therefore, the right call is `root.after(1000, checkText)`.

The full code:

```
def checkText():
    if(text.get("1.0", "end-1c") != currentText):
        print("Changed")

    root.after(1000, checkText)

root.after(1000, checkText)
```

This will effectively schedule the `checkText` function to be called `1000`ms later.

Comment: Thanks for the help and being friendly. Worked perfect and you even gave a wonderful explanation

Comment: @HunterKepley Have fun with Python :)